# Incheon International Airport: Problem with immigration stamp

Tags: layovers, south-korea, korean-air

I just arrived in incheon international airport from LAX earlier today and did not know how to get to the departure area. Hence, I went to the immigration area and got my passport stamped because i thought that that was the way to the departure are. What i didnt know was that that stamp meant that i can no longer go out of the airport. Is there a way that The stamp gets voided so that i can get another one? I really wanted to try the local transit tour since i have a long layover here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you went through immigration, you would have been stamped into Korea, so can hop a bus downtown.  You likely can not catch the transit tour anymore, but you can still explore on your own.

Comment: So you now have your passport stamped twice, one on entry and one on exit? It sounds like you've now technically "left" the country and are simply waiting for your next flight to depart.

Answer (score 1):

After asking the information desk a couple of times (yes, a couple of times with different information officers till i found someone whose english is good enough), they told me that there is no way for me to go outside anymore.